# C++: storing CSV in contianer

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a `std::string` that contains comma separated values, i need to store those values in some suitable container e.g. array, vector or some other container. Is there any built in function through which i could do this? Or i need to write custom code for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're willing and able to use the Boost libraries, [Boost Tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/tokenizer/token_iterator.htm) would work really well for this task.

That would look like:

```
std::string str = "some,comma,separated,words";
typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > tokenizer;
boost::char_separator<char> sep(",");
tokenizer tokens(str, sep);
std::vector<std::string> vec(tokens.begin(), tokens.end());
```

Answer (score 2):

You basically need to tokenize the string using `,` as the delimiter. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c) earlier Stackoverflow thread shall help you with it.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c) is another relevant post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any available in the standard library. I would approach like -

1. Tokenize the string based on `,` delimeter using `strtok`.
2. Convert it to integer using `atoi` function.
3. `push_back` the value to the vector.

If you are comfortable with boost library, [check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

Using AXE parser generator you can easily parse your csv string, e.g.

```
std::string input = "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd";
std::vector<std::string> v; // your strings get here
auto value = *(r_any() - ',') >> r_push_back(v); // rule for single value
auto csv = *(value & ',') & value & r_end(); // rule for csv string
csv(input.begin(), input.end());
```

Disclaimer: I didn't test the code above, it might have some superficial errors.